# Python Sphinx documentation over existing project, KeyError u'language'

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx, keyerror

I'm trying to implement Sphinx documentation over my already finished flask web-applciation.
When i try to run Sphinx using the following command:

`sphinx-apidoc -F -A "MonitoringApplication" -V "0.1" -o docs App`

It creates the rst files for my python scripts but then exits with the following error:
in: `Sphinx\quickstart.py, line 1328, in generate 
conf_text = QUICKSTART_CONF % d
KeyError: u'language`

Google on this Error didn't do me much good so I came here!
extra information:

Sphinx version 1.3b1-py2.7,
OS: Windows 7, Sphinx running in Virtual environment (venv)

Project directory example:

```
App/
  --MoitoringApplication.py
  --models.py
  --database.py
  --functions.py
  --etc.py
  templates/
    --index.html
    --overview.html
    --etc.html
  static/
    --jquery.js
    --etc.js
    images/
      --logo.jpg
```

Running the Sphinx-apidoc command the following directories were built:

```
docs/
  _build/
    ..
  _static/
    ..
  _templates/
    ..
  --MonitoringApplication.rst
  --functions.rst
  --models.rst
  --database.rst
  --etc.rst
```

Am I using the wrong commands or are my directories incorrectly ordered or is it a different Sphinx version that I need?
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I missed `__init__`.py in my package.

Also needed to add `sys.path.append("../App")` in `config.py`.

Then used **sphinx-apidoc** to generate new .rst files.

Then did `make html` which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the language in your Sphinx configuration file, for example:

```
# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
language = 'de'
```